# Oracle Sql table and queries using REFERENCES

Tags: oracle

how to find the number of employees who are supervised by John, who
is supervised by Danny using REFERENCES oracle sql. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add sample data for people to help you.

Comment: What???  Please read [ask] and post sufficient details.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   employees e
WHERE  e.supervisor.name = 'John'
AND    e.supervisor.supervisor.name = 'Danny';
```

Assuming you have the type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE employee AS OBJECT(
  name       VARCHAR2(8),
  supervisor REF employee
);
```

And then the object-derived table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees OF employee;
```